# 'IndexError: tuple index out of range' whith str.format

Tags: python, string, formatting

What am I doing wrong?

```
print('script executed in {time}{1:.2f} seconds'.format(time=elapsed_time))
```

I get:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Expected output:

```
script executed in 0.12 seconds
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You created two format fields:

```
print('script executed in {time}{1:.2f} seconds'.format(time=elapsed_time))
#                         ^1    ^2
```

but only gave one argument to `str.format`:

```
print('script executed in {time}{1:.2f} seconds'.format(time=elapsed_time))
#                                                       ^1
```

You need to have the number of format fields match the number of arguments:

```
print('script executed in {time:.2f} seconds'.format(time=elapsed_time))
```

Comment: Strange error message.  It hints that Python uses tuples for parameter passing but that's not true afaik.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
>>> 'script executed in {:.2f} seconds'.format(elapsed_time)
'script executed in 0.12 seconds'
```

In your original code, you have two `{}` fields, but only gave one argument, which is why it gave the "tuple index out of range" error.